# Visual Studio's IMMEDIATE WINDOW, does not let me run Selenium code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, immediate-window

trying to use VS Immediate Window to evaluate next line after a breakpoint.
For example :  copying and pasting the following line into the Immediate Window:

driver.FindElement(By.Id("3149335")); it never evaluates anything for me !

after copying the line that I need to evaluate in Immediate window , I hit the enter Key to process it and I get the following :

***driver.FindElement(By.Id("3149335"));
Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation.***

Comment: Did you try using the Watch window?